# how to disable ssh user connecting with weak crypto

Tags: ssh

Do you know how to reject SSH user connecting with weak crypto lik DES?

Thanks/

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Protocol` and `Ciphers` options for sshd to restrict the algorithms the client is allowed to use.

Comment: "Ciphers" has its own defaults. If clients don't meet my set ciphers,  sshd reverts its defaults which are aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,
   arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,
   aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr